# Setting the DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding as a URI Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, uri, datagridcolumn

Not sure how to go about this.  I am trying to set-up a `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` in the code-behind so that all the links point to the same URI but each has a different attribute value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DataGridHyperlinkColumn dgCol = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn();
dgCol.Header = title;
dgCol.ContentBinding = new Binding("PersonName");

dgCol.Binding = "PersonEditPage.xaml?PersonID=" + Binding("PersonID");
```

Of course `dgCol.Binding` is expecting a Binding object and so I can't just add a string to this.  Can you please help me to create this binding correctly?

I have not been able to find anything helpful, but maybe this is because I don't know what I should be looking for.  Here are some things I have been looking at (If I missed something please forgive me):

- [MSDN Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Post About Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333544/340045)
- [WPF Navigation](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation)
- [Post on URI Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12444816/340045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a converter in order to format a URL string that contains the `PersonID` of the current property:

```
DataGridHyperlinkColumn hypCol = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn();
hypCol.Header = "Link";
hypCol.ContentBinding = new Binding("PersonName");
hypCol.Binding = new Binding("PersonID") {
    Converter = new FormatStringConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = "PersonEditPage.xaml?PersonID={0}"
};
```

The converter is defined as follows:

```
public class FormatStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I guess that the `Binding.StringFormat` property doesn't work because the binding is expected to convert to a URI and not a string.  Is this right?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, the `StringFormat` property can be used only if the target property has data type `string`.